# subsetting data loses all my observations

Tags: r, subset

I have a data-frame "Test" I wish to subset, but when I try I lose all observations. Why is this happening?

```
> str(Test)
'data.frame':   157025 obs. of  13 variables:
$ Cancellations    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Benefit          : chr  "Single Parent Support                          "               "Single Parent Support                          " "Job Seeker                                         " "Job Seeker                                     " ...
$ Region           : chr  "        Northland    " "        Northland    " "            Northland    " "        Northland    " ...
$ Month            : chr  "Jun 14" "Jun 14" "Jun 14" "Jun 14" ...
$ CanReason        : chr  "Change in Marital Status           " "Change in     Marital Status           " "Change in Marital Status           " "Change in     Marital Status           " ...
$ Age              : chr  " 20-24 " " 20-24 " " 20-24 " " 20-24 " ...
$ Ethnicity        : chr  "NZ European/Pakeha" "Maori             " "Other                      " "NZ European/Pakeha" ...
$ SMS              : chr  "General Case Management               " "Work     Focused Case Management          " "Work Focused Case Management          " "Work     Search Support                   " ...
$ Duration         : chr  "2-4 yrs " "2-4 yrs " "6-9 mth " "0-3 mth " ...
$ SMSDuration      : int  361 348 59 69 150 37 63 294 107 107 ...
$ AgeYoungest      : chr  "0-4 yrs    " "0-4 yrs    " "No Children" "No    Children" ...
$ AgeYoungestNonSub: chr  "0-4 yrs" "0-4 yrs" "No Children" "No Children" ...
$ Liability        : chr  " 166,000 " " 166,000 " " 102,000 " " 102,000 " ...


> subDie <- Test[CanReason == "Died",]

> str(subDie)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  13 variables:
$ Cancellations    : int 
$ Benefit          : chr 
$ Region           : chr 
$ Month            : chr 
$ CanReason        : chr 
$ Age              : chr 
$ Ethnicity        : chr 
$ SMS              : chr 
$ Duration         : chr 
$ SMSDuration      : int 
$ AgeYoungest      : chr 
$ AgeYoungestNonSub: chr 
$ Liability        : chr
```

I have tried turning factor variables into characters. And when I place the comma in front of "CanReason" indexing row (subDie <- Test[, CanReason == "Died"]) R tells me i have 157025 observations on 0 variables....
Im stumped

Comment: Is it "Died" or "Died"+extra spaces?

Comment: It's probably because of the extra spaces @Pascal mentioned, but a `dput(head(Test))`would be more useful than `str`.

Comment: I just tried 
- "Died " (1 extra space)
- "Died  " (2 extra spaces)
- "Died   " (3 extra spaces)
No such luck.

Comment: For example, "Change in Marital Status" has 10 extra spaces, as you can see in the output of `str`. You cannot guess the number of extra space by chance.

Comment: Can you show the output of `sort(unique(Test$CanReason))`?

Comment: I keep a `trim`- function around to strip off leading and trailing spaces from column names.

Comment: Thanks @Pascal! I wouldn't have noticed the spaces on my own, with them out of the excel data sheet everything is functioning fine.
LIfesaver!!

Answer (score 1):

Search for the string `"Died"` in the character vector `CanReason` using a regular expression, using `grepl()` to return a logical vector indicating a match or not. Use that to subset `Test`.

For example

```
set.seed(12)
CanReason <- sample(c("Change in      Marital status",
                      "Change in   Marital status ",
                      " Died    ",
                      "Died                ",
                      "Died"), 10000, replace = TRUE)
ind <- grepl("Died", CanReason)

sum(ind)
length(CanReason[ind])
```

Giving:

```
> sum(ind)
[1] 6037
> length(CanReason[ind])
[1] 6037
> head(CanReason[ind])
[1] "Died"                 "Died"                 "Died                "
[4] "Died"                 " Died    "            " Died    "
```